# Shell subcommand output to parent command

Tags: bash, shell, command, pipe

I have a one line command, lets say

```
grep needle haystack.file
```

What if i wanted to replace "needle" with the current working directory using the pwd command. Now it might be possible using pipes but I need the needle part to show the working directory and the rest of the command to be the same.

So preferably something like this:

```
grep (pwd) haystack.file
```

Which when executed would actually run the following command:

```
grep /var/www/html/ haystack.file
```

I've done a bit of searching and have found a lot of examples with pipes but it cant be applied in my scenario as the first part (grep) and second part (haystack.file) is fixed in an application.

Answer (score 5):

Use the `$PWD` variable, always set:

```
grep "$PWD" haystack.file
```

You can also use command substitution:

```
grep "$(pwd)" haystack.file
```

Note the importance of quotes. Do it! Otherwise strange things can happen.

Comment: ``grep `pwd` haystack.file`` would work as well, as long as there's no IFS chars in the path.

Comment: Yes! Only that I tend not to use ``: they cannot be nested :(

Comment: @MarcB It does but there is literally no reason to use `\`pwd\`` over `"$(pwd)"` and many reasons not to.

Answer (score 5):

You can use command substitution

**Test**

```
$ echo $(pwd) > test
$ grep $(pwd) test
/home/xxx/yyy
```

**OR**

```
$ grep `pwd` test
/home/xxx/yyy
```

**Security**

It's always recomended to quote the command substituion to take care of the spaces in the output of `pwd` command

**Test**

```
$ pwd
/home/xxx/yyy/hello world
$(pwd) > test

$ grep $(pwd) test #without quoting
grep: world: No such file or directory
test:/home/xxx/yyy/hello world

$ grep "$(pwd)" test #with quoting
/home/xxx/yyy/hello world
```